# MySQL - How to the AVG ON SUM?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to calculate the average on the sum of every row but I didn't succeed. 
Also, I ask you for helping to me.

```
id   sessionId   duration
1    5           10
2    5           12
3    14          5
4    14          5
5    21          7
6    21          12
```

Result:

```
sessionId    sum
5            22
14           10
21           19
```

2nd result sum:

```
  22+10+19 = 51
```

Average

```
51/3 = 17
```

This i my sql:

```
SELECT `SessionID`
     , SUM(`Duration (s)`) AS SOMME_total 
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`Duration (s)`)) AS SOMME_HEURE 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT SUM(i2.`Duration (s)`) AS SOMME_ROW 
         FROM issueNubitalk i2 
        WHERE i2.Campaign LIKE 'Canal%' 
        GROUP 
           BY i2.SessionID
     )
```

Comment: This query would result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the `SUM` by distinct `COUNT`:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) / COUNT(DISTINCT sessionId)
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(duration)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(duration) AS duration
    FROM issueNubitalk
    GROUP BY sessionId
) t;
```

I am using the column names from your sample data, which don't appear to line up entirely with your query.  But the above answer would probably be more beneficial to future readers of this question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could calc the avg fo the result

```
select avg(T.SOMME_total) 
from (
  SELECT `SessionID`
    , SUM(`Duration (s)`) AS SOMME_total 
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`Duration (s)`)) AS SOMME_HEURE 
  FROM FROM issueNubitalk i2 
      WHERE i2.`Campaign` 
      LIKE 'Canal%' 
  GROUP by i2.`SessionID`
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get result as you need its written in PostgreSQL and you can convery it in MYSQL easily.

```
SELECT
  average_value.totalSum/average_value.totalCount AS averageValue
FROM
(
  SELECT
   count(*) as totalCount,
   sum(total_value.sum) as totalSum
  FROM (
     SELECT
       i2.SessionID,
       sum(i2.Duration) as sum
     FROM issueNubitalk i2
     WHERE
      i2.`Campaign` LIKE 'Canal%' 
     GROUP BY i2.SessionID
  ) total_value
  ) average_value;
```

Comment: Yes, it works well. I decided adding a condition sous  
WHERE i2.`Campaign` LIKE 'Canal%'  AND i2.`BusinessOutcome` LIKE ' '
His result is wrong because the statistics is very big. I find strange

Comment: Adding more coditions never change your outcomes please try once again and check that you are using correct syntex and also check that it is returning values after search...Thanks